# Требуется ли в этом предложении запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

Из за множества плохих отметок в школе(,) твоих родителей просят прийти в школу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причинный оборот не обособляется только тогда, когда стоит под ударением. Взгляните на несколько примеров с контекстами:

— Моих родителей вызывают из-за той драки?
— Твоих родителей просят прийти в школу из-за множества плохих отметок в школе. (ударение на причинный оборот, поэтому он не обособляется)

— Вы хотели меня видеть? Зачем вы меня вызвали?
— Твоих родителей просят прийти в школу, из-за множества плохих отметок в школе.(ударение не на причинный оборот)

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, предлог [**из-за**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0&all=x) пишется с дефисом.

Во-вторых, следует избегать ненужных повторов в предложении: в школе, в школу (ведь и так понятно, где ученик получил плохие отметки — раз вызывают именно в школу).

В-третьих, оборот с предлогом "из-за" может, конечно, обособляться. Но в этом простом предложении он нераспространенный — запятая не требуется.

**Из-за множества плохих отметок твоих родителей просят прийти в школу.**

Из-за множества стоящих впритирку друг к другу коек плац был похож на двор автомобильного завода или тракторного комбината... [Виктор Пелевин. Омон Ра (1992)]

[Обособленные дополнения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=116)